# Array Objects not showing up

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to take objects from one array when they are clicked and put them in the other and attempt to show them else where.

So far just for trying out purposes I am experimenting with one object, but even that is not working out too well. the objects are disappearing fine, but they are not reappearing on the stage. can somebody please help me with this?

```
function removeItemOnClick(in_event:MouseEvent):void
{

    var i:int = 0;
    for (i=0; i<socket_Array.length; i++)
    {

        if (socket_Array[i] == in_event.target)
        {

            trace("it goes here");
            socket_Array[i].visible = false;
            trace(socket_Array );
            var removed = socket_Array.splice(i,1);
            trace(removed);
            removedItem[removedItem.length] = removed;
            removedItem_placement();
            updateDisplay();
        }
    }
}

function removedItem_placement()
{
    var i:int = 0;
    for (i=0; i < removedItem.length; i++)
    {

        trace("The removed Item x is " + removedItem [i].x );
        trace("The removed Item y is " + removedItem [i].y );
        trace("The removed Item visibility " + removedItem [i].visible );
        trace("The removed Item " + removedItem);
        removedItem[i].visible = true;
        removedItem[i].x = 0;
        removedItem[i].y = 0;
        trace("The removed Item x is " + removedItem [i].x );
        trace("The removed Item y is " + removedItem [i].y );
        trace("The removed Item visibility " + removedItem [i].visible );

    }
}
```

Comment: is it outputs errors?

Answer (score 0):

Note that removed is of type Array since Array.splice has Array as return type.
removedItem is also an array, so you can barely do the assignment `removedItem[removedItem.length] = removed;`.

Try instead `removedItem.concat(removed);`

I would also recommend to add a `break` statement after updateDisplay() since you can have only one matching element at a time.

Comment: .concat doesn't work. it doesn't transfer the object all together. but there may be an issue with the way i am assigning, cna u please tell me another method from which i can assign the spliced item to an array. becuase when I do it by assigning it the spliced item it does transfer but it doesn't replace it self.